# Is mysql_real_escape_string is really safe to use?

Tags: php, mysql

OK, I have one question before I start coding MySQL in my school project. Is mysql_real_escape_string is really safe to use? I've heard that it's still not really safe to use..So are there any tweaks which makes SQL query secure? I've used mysql_real_escape_string before many times, but not I am building a website for my school, so first thing I've to check is security.

Comment: I think what you really want to know is: "Is using `mysql_real_escape_string()` the only thing I should worry about with regard to security?"  Answer:  no, but it's a good start.

Comment: This might help: [importance of link identifier in mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977886/importance-of-link-identifier-in-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is quite old fashionned, php version is now 5.3 and above: use PDO !

Comment: I'd like to hear why it's not safe to use.

Comment: @tandu - no one said it's not safe to use, there are just better methods out there as hornetbzz said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The answer below was to the best of my knowledge correct at the time of writing.  The fact is mysql_real_escape_string is not safe and never really was.  You should always use prepared statements instead.

As mysql_* has been removed completely as of PHP 7 the situation has become moot.  I've left my original answer for historical purposes below.

---

mysql_real_escape_string is safe to use if used properly (ie, everywhere you're inserting PHP variables into your queries), but as has been pointed out in the comments it's not the only thing you need to worry about. For example, HTML markup could be inserted into your DB and used for Cross Site Scripting attacks.

You might also want to consider prepared statements as an alternative to mysql_real_escape_string, as they will automatically escape input for you so there's no chance of accidentally forgetting to escape a parameter.

Comment: it's critical to ensure you use mysql_real_escape_string() and NOT the bad old mysql_escape_string() if you must stick to using the old mysql legacy db library in php

Comment: @Ray i know your comment is old but if you need to use the old legacy MySQL library in PHP for some wierd reason atleast use MySQL's native [Prepared SQL Statement Syntax (MYSQL 5.5+)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to get protection against SQL injections the `EXECUTE stmt1 USING @<variable>` approach is safe  .. But keep in mind using `CONCAT()` how the manual uses it can be prone again to SQL injections.